# Supervised ML to extract keywords from short texts

Tags: python, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have a lot training data ready and looking for an ML algorithm to replace the current algorithms.
The input is a paragraph containing a short biography of a person and the output is their dates of birth and name.
What algorithm can output a set of keywords based on short texts?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition, Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: No I'm looking to train on existing entity values